# Recursion. How to make a program that inputs a sequence of integers and outputs a number equal to zero?

Tags: java, recursion

I need a program that takes a sequence of integers and outputs a number equal to zero. Assume that
numbers are numbered from one, if there are no zeros, then output zero, but if several numbers are entered, which are equal to zero, then output the number of the last zero.

Special requirements for the program:

- Do not use the operator package.
- Input errors are not allowed to be processed.
- It is forbidden to use loop operators (for, while, do-while). Loop organization must use recursion,
  the number of methods is not limited.

the program must perform the following steps:

- The statement "count:" must be issued and the amount of numbers must be entered.
- The statement "numbers:" must be issued and a sequence of numbers must be entered.
- The statement "result:" must be issued and after the given statement the number of the last zero must be issued (in the same line, separate the number from the "result:" statement with one space character).

I was given this code, but unfortunately I am no coder and that is why I am seeking help here.

Note that code must be edited in order for the program to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    
    static Scanner sc; 
    
    public static boolean checkNumbers(int n) {
        int x;
        x = sc.nextInt();
        
        return check(n-1, x, true);
    }
    
    private static boolean check(int n, int prevNum, boolean flag) {
        int x;
        if (n==0) {
            return flag;
        }
        else {
            x = sc.nextInt();
            flag = flag && x >= prevNum;
            return check(n-1, x, flag);
        }
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int count;
        System.out.print("count:");
        count = sc.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("numbers:");
        boolean result = checkNumbers(count); 
        
        System.out.print("result:");
        if (result)
            System.out.println(1);
        else
            System.out.println(2);
        
        sc.close();
```

Comment: 'but if several numbers are entered, which are equal to zero, then output the number of the last zero.' - what is the number of the last zero? A zero was entered. So do you expect to see zero, or the count of how many other numbers were entered before?

Comment: Assume that every entered number is numbered as if I entered 5,4,3,2,1, then number of 5 will be 1, number of 4 will be 2, etc. If I entered (0,6,2,7,0,3) total count of entered numbers are 6 and the last 0 is number 5.

Comment: "unfortunately I am no coder and that is why I am seeking help here" Please tell us what you have tried. We already know you're not a coder. That's why you've been given this homework. You've been given this homework to learn how to code. But if you're unwilling to even try to solve the problem, you're not going to learn anything.

Comment: I've tried little to nothing, I am willing to do it, but I need some extra help, I was hoping someone could atleast guide me or even make it fully (sounds inefficient for my knowledge, but I would have analyzed it in order to learn the topic better, as it is, my Professor didn't explain this topic quite well).

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is always "fun".

This should help "clear" it up for you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {

  public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main( String [] args) {   
    System.out.print("count:");
    int count = sc.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("numbers:");
    int position = check(1, count); 
    
    System.out.println("result: " + position);
  } 

  public static int check(int curPosition, int maxPosition) {
    return (curPosition > maxPosition) ? 0 : Math.max((sc.nextInt() == 0) ? curPosition : 0, check(curPosition + 1, maxPosition));
  }
  
}
```

The return value of the recursive function is of type `int` and will represent the largest position of any entered zeroes. The first parameter to the function is the current position of the number being typed in by the user, which starts at 1 (note the hard-coded 1 in the call within `main()`). The second parameter is the number of numbers the user is entering; which doesn't change from call to call.

Each recursive call increments the current position by adding one to the previous value. When the current position exceeds the number of numbers needed to be typed in by the user, we simply return zero.

If the current position is less than the number of numbers needed to be entered, then we get a number from the user and compare it to zero. If the number entered is zero, then we return whatever is bigger, the current position or the return value of any recursive calls. If the entered number is not a zero, then we return whatever is bigger, zero or the return value of any recursive calls.